# Is WebGL's MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE the max area, diameter, or bytes?

Tags: webgl

It's kind of interesting how much documentation avoids disambiguating what `WebGLRenderingContext#getParameter(WebGLRenderingContext.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` means. "Size" is not very specific.

Is it the maximum *storage size* of textures in bytes, implying lowering bit-depth or using fewer color channels increases the maximum dimensions? Is it the maximum *diameter in pixels* of textures, implying you are much more limited in terms of addressable-area if your textures are highly rectangular? Is it the maximum *number of pixels*?

Comment: WebGL, as it says in the WebGL spec, is based on OpenGL ES 2.0. The OpenGL ES 2.0 spec, section 3.7.1 says *The maximum allowable width and height of a two-dimensional texture image must be at least 2
^(k−lod) for image arrays of level zero through k, where k is the log
base 2 of `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and lod is the level-of-detail of the image array. It may be zero for image arrays of any level-of-detail greater than k.*

Comment: @gman As it stands, your comment is a better answer than the actual self-provided answer. If you'd move it there I'd vote it up, *because I do think this question has merit*. The WebGL -> OpenGL ES indirection as well as the wording in the spec itself don't make it very discoverable for WebGL newcomers.

Comment: Yea, specs are often hard to read. WebGL just defines the JavaScript interface and minor differences. The main spec is still the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec. It says that right in one of the opening paragraphs "*The remaining sections of this document are intended to be read in conjunction with the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification*".  That spec is 204 pages long. It would have been a huge waste of time to include those pages so they just linked to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it says in the [WebGL spec section 1.1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/)

> The remaining sections of this document are intended to be read in conjunction with the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification (2.0.25 at the time of this writing, available from the Khronos OpenGL ES API Registry). Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of each method is defined by the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification

The [OpenGL ES 2.0.25 spec, section 3.7.1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) says

> The maximum allowable width and height of a two-dimensional texture image must be at least `2^(k−lod)` for image arrays of level zero through k, where k is the log base 2 of `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and lod is the level-of-detail of the image array.

It's the largest width and/or height you can specify for a texture. Note that this has nothing to do with memory as @Strilanc points out. So while you can probably create a `1 x MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` or a `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE x 1` texture you probably can not create a `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE x MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` texture as you'd run out of memory

Answer (score 2):

It's the **maximum diameter in pixels**. If `M` is the maximum texture size, then you can create textures of size `M x M`, `M/2 x M/4`, `M x 1`, and so on; but you can't make a texture of size `2M x 2M` or `1 x 2M`.

Consider that the largest MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE reported in [this opengl capability report](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE) is 16384 (2^15). If that was the maximum number of pixels (nevermind *bytes*), instead of the maximum diameter, you'd be unable to create 256x256 textures. Which is *really small*.

(Note that limits besides MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE apply. For example, my machine returns a maximum texture size of 2^15. But a 2^15 x 2^15 texture with rgba float pixels would take 16 gibibytes of space. It wouldn't fit in the available memory.)

Comment: While the essence of your answer is correct, I don't think "diameter" means what you think it does. This makes your current answer kind of misleading.

Comment: @Paul-Jan I guess what I had in mind is more like "axis-aligned diameter".