# Why can I use textures bigger than MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE (WebGL)?

Tags: webgl, textures, pixi.js

According to this thread, my MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192 :
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109392/how-to-find-out-max-texture-size-for-webgl-on-my-system)

And according to this thread, MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE actually defines the maximum of the largest size of my texture : [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946523/is-webgls-max-texture-size-the-max-area-diameter-or-bytes)

Yet, I can use a texture of 8500 x 60 (the texture is a spritesheet) without error in PIXI V7.2.4 webworker :

```
PIXI.Assets.add('myBigSpriteSheet', '../resources/myBigSpriteSheet.png');
PIXI.Assets.load(['myBigSpriteSheet']).then((textures) =>
{
    let myBigSpriteSheet = textures['myBigSpriteSheet'];
    
    for (let i=0; i<100; i++)
        _textures['grass/'+i] = new PIXI.Texture(myBigSpriteSheet, new PIXI.Rectangle(i*58, 0, 58, 30));
```

Does anybody know why ?

Could it be because I never load the full texture in my sprites, but only parts of it (using PIIX.Rectangles) ? If so, does actually MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE apply to the rectangles and not the texture itself ? I guess not, reading this thread, but I would like to understand :) [text](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/6372)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can use a texture of 8500 x 60 without errors might be because you are not actually loading the entire texture at once. You are using PIXI. Rectangles to specify smaller regions of the larger texture when creating new textures. PIXI.js is smart enough to load and manage only the portions of the texture that are actually being used.

and the `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` typically applies to individual textures, not to the sum of all textures in use. So, as long as the individual rectangles you define for your sprites stay within the `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` limits, you should not encounter issues.

Comment: Incredible ! 
No limit then, except GPU memory :D
Thank you !

Comment: Well, after doing some tests, it appears that if I use a mega texture of 58 x 13000, my sprites are black while if I use a smaller one (58 x 1000), they are not. I guess I should have an error somewhere if I overpass GPU memory ? If so... I guess PIXI is actually not as smart as you say. Then I am not really sure of what MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE defines !

Comment: So I did some other tests ! Indeed, if I use a texture of 8100 height x 58 (< 8192), sprites appears correctly. But if I use a bigger one, 8300 height x 58 (> 8192), they are black. PIXI loader won't notify, you will just get the final result when trying to display sprites on screen. So, indeed, 8192 is the limit :)